# How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nn^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is convergent if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$

Tags: convergence-divergence

How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} a_n$ is convergent. Where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent.

I know that

Abel's Test: Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent and the sequence $<b_n>$ is monotonic and bounded then
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ is convergent.
I don't know how to apply this test. Please help me.

Comment: Is $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ eventually monotonic? Is it bounded? If the answer to both of these questions is yes, what can you say about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\frac{1}{n}}a_n$?

Comment: Here $0 \leq n^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq 1$ but I'm unable to show $n^{\frac{1}{n}} > {(n+1)}^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$, for all $n$

Comment: @LargestPrime:  No, $n^{\frac 1n} \gt 1$ when $n \gt 1$, but it doesn't get too large.

Comment: Ohh yes, but how to show monotonicity with simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\sum (n^{1/n}-1)a_n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n}-1=0$ and $n^{1/n}-1$ is eventually monotonically decreasing (for $n\ge 4$), moreover the partial sums of $\sum a_n$ are bounded. So by Abel-Dirichlet test $\sum (n^{1/n}-1)a_n$ is converging. Adding $\sum a_n$ we get that $\sum n^{1/n}a_n$ is converging.

**Proof** that $n^{1/n}$ is decreasing for $n\ge 4$.

$$n^{1/n}\quad ? \quad (n+1)^{1/(n+1)}$$ iff $$n^{n+1}\quad ? \quad (n+1)^n$$
where $?$ is $"<"$ or $">"$ (we shall prove that $?=">"$).

By the binomial formula,

\begin{align*}
(n+1)^n &= n^n+nn^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} n^{n-2}+\dots+\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}n^{n-k}+\dots+1 \\
&< n^n+\frac{n^n}{1!}+\frac{n^n}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{n^n}{k!}+\cdots+\frac{n^n}{n!} \\
&\le n^n(1+1+\frac1{2!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!}) \\
&< n^n(1+e).
\end{align*}
So $n^{1/n}>(1+n)^{1/(1+n)}$ if $n>1+e$ and in fact $?=">"$ indeed.

Comment: OK... What is your last part? Please use proper MathJax.

Comment: I am trying to use proper MathJax, proving that $n^{1/n}$ is decreasing starting with $n=4$. I think it is now readable, but the long formula should be split into parts.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$ n^{1/n} \ge 1 \iff n \ge 1^n$$

and

$$ n^{1/n} \le 2 \iff n \le 2^n$$

In other words $n^{1/n} \in [1,2]$ for $n \ge 1$.

A good place to start understanding the function $x^{1/x}$ is to graph it. You can see visually that $x^{1/x} \in [1,2]$ for $x \ge 1$ and you can see that it is decreasing if $x \ge e$ (2.718...). You can then try to prove these statements analytically (e.g. compute the derivative).